# threejs compressed texture pc/mobile android/ios/chrome compatibility

Tags: android, ios, three.js

I have a sequence of images/textures to display with `threejs`.

- Firstly I loaded a lot of Raw RGB format data (*Uint8Array*) and fed into **THREE.DataTexture**. It was fine on PC and Android but seemed to hit the memory-bound and caused *page reload* on iOS safari.

  ```
  var texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, w, h, THREE.RGBFormat);
  ```

What is the best way to have a lot of texture or texture data in memory for `threejs` to use?

*Must be compatible with PC/Android/iOS.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I changed all the data to **Compressed Texture Formats** and use [THREE.CompressedTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CompressedTexture), for example Dxt1, to reduce memory usage. But DXT1 only works for PC.

  ```
  // given texture_data, texutre_width, texture_height
  var texture = new THREE.CompressedTexture(null, texture_width, texture_height,
    THREE.RGB_S3TC_DXT1_Format, THREE.UnsignedByteType, THREE.UVMapping,
    THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping, THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    THREE.LinearFilter, THREE.LinearFilter);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

  // create mipmaps with data
  var mipmap = { 
    "data": texture_data,
    "width": texture_width, 
    "height": texture_height 
  };
  var mipmaps = [];
  mipmaps.push(mipmap);

  // set data to texture and update
  texture.mipmaps = mipmaps;
  texture.needsUpdate = true
  material.needsUpdate = true;
  ```
- Going forward, I found that the compatibility of compressed texture formats across platforms was an issue. Each format requires a certain WEBGL extension. For example Dxt1 requires [S3TC extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc/).

  ```
  if (renderer.extensions.get('WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc'))
    alert('WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc is supported');
  else
    alert('WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc is NOT supported');
  ```
- There was not one format that works for all three platforms(PC/iOS/Android). Details below:

  - ASTC/ETC/ETC1: only works for Android
  - ATC: don't work at all platforms
  - PVRTC: only works for iOS
  - S3TC/S3TC_SRGB: only works for PC
- Another way was to encode all the textures to **mp4**, but decoding them to raw texture was not easy. I tried [Broadway](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway/issues/212). It works but the cpu loading was heavy.
- At last, I encoded all the data to [basis](https://github.com/BinomialLLC/basis_universal/) format and use [BasisTextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/zh/loaders/BasisTextureLoader) to load them on browser. The compress rate was similar to *h264 baseline*, way better than *dxt1*.
- **BasisTextureLoader** actually detects the compatibility at runtime and decode them to a certain CompressedTexture format for `threejs` to use.

Hope it helps.